# Naming classes and namespaces the same?

Tags: c#, .net, naming-conventions

I'm a beginner on C# (I know Java well though) and came to a problem with naming namespaces and classes/interfaces the same.

What won't work is this:

```
- Projekt
--> (Interface) Node
--> (Namespace/Folder) Node
-----> (Class): SomethingNode : Node
-----> ...
```

Because there is an error that the type "Project.Node" and the Namespace "Project.Node" are named the same.

I will explain why I would intentionally like to name those the same: I have many classes who implement the interface "Node". Those classes should all be in one namespace, so why don't name them "Node" I thought. The Interface "Node" should be in the project's root namespace, because it's used by other classes and I don't want to e.g. move the interface "Node" to "Project.Node.Node", because I think it would be silly to allways import "Project.Node" just because I need the interface.

So my question is, how should I resolve this situation? How should I name my classes/namespaces, is there a nice elegant way of doing this, are there any naming conventions for this kind of situation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should follow .NET conventions and name your interface `INode`. Then classes inside the **Node** namespace will implement your `INode` interface.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I have another situation like this, but not with an interface. I would like to have a Singleton names "Library" which contains lists of other classes, let's say predefined methods (like a code library). I would intentionally name the namespace for the methods i can add in "Library" too, though... is there something equal I can do for this kind of situation, or do I simply have to think for another name for the namespace?

Comment: Pretty much. There are 'tricks' though. Pluralisation. System.Windows. Forms contains a Form type. Although I think you are better off describing what the namespace contains. LibraryComponents or something along those lines.

Comment: You can find the official .NET naming guidelines for interfaces here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bc1fexb(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution to the problem is simply to adopt the C#/.NET naming convention for interfaces, which is to add an I - `INode`, not the Java-esque `Node`. Also, it SHOULD sit under the Nodes namespace. Importing a namespace isn't a cumbersome action, especially as most IDEs, and certainly Visual Studio, can automate it for you. It prevent your root namespace from being crowded and unbrowsable.

Secondly, I think that a more intuitive name for a namespace is using the plural: `Projekt.Nodes`, so you'll have this:

```
namespace Projekt
{
    namespace Nodes
    {
        public interface INode { }
        public class Node : INode { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically namespaces in .Net are very similar to packages in Java. You could get around this by calling your Interface INode. It is a .Net convention to prefix an interface with the letter I. Silly, Hungarian notation, but silly conventions are what .Net developers are used to anyway ;-)

Comment: Damn those silly .net users for being used to something that makes complete sense.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to have name collisions between types and namespaces. Then there's the .Net convention of prefixing interfaces with a capital 'i', so your interface `Node` would then become `INode`. This is a standard among all libraries and components of the .Net framework. Applying the standard to your code should easily solve your problem of collisions.

Now in my opinion, from an architectual point of view, if all implementations of `INode` are under the Node namespace, I'd also expect to find `INode` under it as well.